# SelectList when using EditorFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, mvc-editor-templates, data-annotations

i have come across a strange behaviour when trying to get a `SelectList` to display correctly when using the `Html.EditorForModel()`.

I have the following `Model`:

```
public class LoginModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }

    public string Gender { get; set; }

    [UIHint("SelectList")]
    public SelectList AvailibleGender { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, I have a `SelectList` item that holds the values to get put into the Gender string. I have overriden the `SelectList EditorTemplate`, which for now has a simple script tag showing an alert box.

When I use `EditorFor(m=>AvailableGender)`, my alert box fires, which means the editor correctly chose my SelectList template.

When I use `EditorForModel()`, my alert box does not fire.

If I change the model as follows:

```
[UIHint("SelectList")]
public string AvailibleGender { get; set; }
```

..then my SelectList template does get hit, and I see the alert message.

So it looks like there is something specifically blocking the SelectList.

In case it is something to do with specific custom types, I tried adding an `object.cshtml` file, but this doesn't get invoked either. so it seems that the `SelectList` type is getting lost somewhere.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get the Select List working with EditorForModel()?

Comment: That seems like an odd way to set up your model, mixing domain with UI. Are you really editing the available genders, or are you using available genders as options to edit `Gender`? I would probably make `Gender` an `enum`, and created a custom dropdown template to display enum values.

Comment: I am using the SelectList to list Male/Female, that sets the Gender value on postback.